# How do I remove duplicates from a dict{} by comparing part of the value, stored using tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I am having trouble removing duplicates from a dict{}. The dict{} is built like this:

```
tuple = (plugin, risk, addr, Name, InstanceId, profile, Brief, Description, Synopsis, See_Also, Solution, References, Plugin_Output)

plugin_ec2[counter] = tuple[0:13]
```

I use this function to remove duplicate values from my dict{}.

```
def dup_remove(dup_list):
unique_list= {}
for key, value in dup_list.items():
    if value not in unique_list.values():
        unique_list[key] = value

return unique_list
```

The dict{} plugin_ec2 gets very long, and is filled with duplicates. I would like to remove duplicates in my dict{} only based on the values from plugin_ec2[key][0:8], but save the new unique_dict with the entire plugin_ec2 values, from [0:13]. This is becuase the values between [8:13] may be different.

I need something like this

```
def dup_remove(dup_list):
unique_list= {}
for key, value in dup_list.items():
    if value**[0:8]** not in unique_list.values()**[0:8]**:
        unique_list[key] = value

return unique_list
```

Do you guyz have any ideas? I am struggling and I need help.

Thank you for looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you keep a set of seen `value[0:8]` tuples? Someting like:

```
def dup_remove(dup_list):
    seen_subvalues = set()
    unique_list = {}
    for key, value in dup_list.items():
        subvalue = value[0:8]
        if subvalue not in seen_subvalues:
            unique_list[key] = value
            seen_subvalues.add(subvalue)

    return unique_list
```

Looking for a value into the set is faster (`O(1)` vs `O(n)` in `dup_list.values()`). <sub>By the way, don't call a dictionary `xxx_list`. Try something like `value_by_key` (replace `value` and `key` by more specific names if possible).</sub>

I would write a more generic function like this:

```
def dup_remove(d, key = lambda v: v):
    seen = set()
    unique = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        value = key(v)
        if value not in seen:
            unique[k] = v
            seen.add(value)

    return unique
```

Example:

```
>>> dup_remove({'1': 'a ', '2': 'a', '3': 'b', '4': '  a'}, str.strip)
>>> {'1': 'a ', '3': 'b'}
```

The `2` and `4` keys where removed because `'a '.strip() == 'a'.strip() == '  a'.strip()`

In your case, you can use it like that:

```
dup_remove(plugin_ec2, lambda v: v[:8])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I never new about lambda passed as function params. You made my day!